# Themepunch revolution slider does not work correctly when using ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I trying to use slider revolution provided by Themepunch on my website (developed in Angular 8) with dynamic data that is coming for a JSON file. Therefore, I have required CSS and js files in the index.html like this

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!--Css Files-->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

  //Here is the css files
  <link href="assets/css/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/rs-plugin/css/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root> 

  <!-- js Files -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap-4.js"></script>

  // Here is the js files
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>

  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I use a component to show the slider as a banner. In that component I use asyc call to get the json from the json file and update the array and in the component HMTL I use ngFor loop it bind the array data. However, the silder is not showing any data bacause of the ngFor and if I remove it, then the data will show.

Here is the typescript code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private file: FileService, public translate: TranslateService) { }
  @Input() entity: string;
  @Input() site;
  main_banner: any[] = [];
  revSlider: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initRevolutionSlider();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.file.get(0, 'main_banner').then(r => {
      this.main_banner = r;
    }); 
  }

  get lang(): string {
    return this.translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? '_ar' : '_en';
  }

  identify(index, item) {
    return index;
  }

  counter: number = 0;

  initRevolutionSlider() {
    if ($('#revolutionSlider').get(0)) {
      this.revSlider = $('#revolutionSlider').show().revolution({
        sliderType: 'standard',
        sliderLayout: 'fullscreen',
        delay: 9000,
        responsiveLevels: [4096, 1200, 992, 576],
        gridwidth: [1100, 920, 680, 500],
        gridheight: 740,
        disableProgressBar: 'on',
        spinner: 'spinner3',
        parallax: {
          type: "on",
          levels: [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
          origo: "enterpoint",
          speed: 400,
          bgparallax: "on",
          disable_onmobile: "off"
        },
        navigation: {
          arrows: {
            enable: true
          }
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container">
  <div id="revolutionSlider" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" data-version="5.4.8" >
    <ul>
      <li data-transition="fade" *ngFor="let n of main_banner;trackBy:identify;">
        <img *ngIf="n.banner" src="{{n.banner}}"
             alt=""
             data-bgposition="center center"
             data-bgfit="cover"
             data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"
             data-kenburns="on"
             data-duration="20000"
             data-ease="Linear.easeNone"
             data-scalestart="110"
             data-scaleend="100"
             data-offsetstart="250 100"
             class="rev-slidebg" />

        <h1 class="tp-caption font-weight-bold text-color-light text-center text-white"
            data-x="center"
            data-y="center" data-voffset="['-70','-70','-70','-70']"
            data-width="['770','770','770','350']"
            data-start="1000"
            data-paddingtop="['11','11','11','16']"
            data-paddingbottom="['11','11','11','16']"
            data-fontsize="['50','50','45','35']"
            data-lineheight="['56','56','50','40']"
            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
            data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:500;"
            style="white-space: normal;">
          {{n.name_en}}
        </h1>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a minimal version of your app in Stackblitz or through any other source convinient to you?

Comment: Were you able to find a way out? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to figure out why *ngFor was not working, but I found a work around by following these steps:

0. Clear everything inside the slider 'ul' and give it an id='rev_slider_ul'

   ```
   <!--Slider-->
   <div class="rev_slider_wrapper">
     <div id="rev_slider" class="rev_slider" data-version="5.0">
       <ul id="rev_slider_ul">

       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
1. Import jquery in .ts file.

   `declare var jQuery: any;`
2. Define a method to load the slider with configurations

   ```
   loadSlider(){
       return jQuery("#rev_slider").show().revolution({
           sliderType: "standard",
           sliderLayout: "fullwidth",
           scrollbarDrag: "true",
           navigation: {
           arrows: {
               enable: true
           },
           touch: {
               touchenabled: "on",
               swipe_threshold: 75,
               swipe_min_touches: 1,
               swipe_direction: "horizontal",
               drag_block_vertical: false
           }
           },
           gridwidth: 1170,
           gridheight: 770
       });
   }
   ```
3. Iterate the object you needed to iterate in ts and form a HTML string with it or keep appending to the slider element.

   ```
   data.forEach((elem)=>{
       jQuery("#rev_slider_ul").append(${elem})
   });
   ```
4. Outside and after the forEach loop, load the slider

   `this.loadSlider()`

Hope that helps. Don't see much to explain here, but open to questions if any.